# How to debug Ionic app running on Android emulator in visual studio code in 2020?

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, visual-studio-code

It used to be possible to debug Ionic app running in Android emulator, using the plugin Cordova Tools.

Now in July 2020, when I open the run option, I can no longer see Cordova being listed. Even though I have the plugin installed and enabled.

It's very difficult to work without being able to debug TypeScript, using Chrome developer tools is an option, but debugging transpiled Javascript is not ideal.

I'm not sure what's going on, there's no update on the plugin page, has anyone been able to do this? If not is there an alternative? I don't mind switching to a different text editor or IDE.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know what happened, but was able to attach the debugger to the application using the following steps.

1. Open command line, run Ionic start to create a sample application.
2. Open the sample application's folder in VSC.
3. Click run and choose to create a launch.json file, Cordova appears in the list, choose Cordova.
4. Copy the launch.json file from the sample project to company app's project.
5. Open the company app's project in VSC, under debug choose "Attach to Android running in emulator", or "Run Android in device"... as per usual.

Still have no idea why Cordova is not listed when trying to debug project initially, though.

Comment: This was a pain. So Cordova is indeed not listed in vscode's debug list. I do not understand the part where you said "click run and choose to create a launch.json file". It's not in the command palette